# Generate Sequence of Numbers in R with two digit

Tags: r, string, matrix

I have a matrix,and i need to generate column name to the matrix.
column names should be something like this.

```
"out01"  "out02"  "out03"  "out04" ... to .. "out30"
```

This is what i have tried

```
outmat <- matrix(NA, 5, 30)
colnames(outmat) <- sprintf("out%d", 1:30)
```

generated column names are like this.

```
 "out1"  "out2"  "out3"  "out4"  "out5"  "out6"  "out7"  "out8"  "out9"  "out10" .... to "out30"
```

is there any direct way to covert `out1 to out01` in `sprintf` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, specify `%02d`

```
sprintf("out%02d", 1:30)
#[1] "out01" "out02" "out03" "out04" "out05" "out06" "out07" "out08" "out09"....
```